# Building a truth table for the following expression, confused on comma's within the expression.

Tags: logic

{A $\rightarrow$ B, (C $\rightarrow$ A $\lor$ B), C} $\models$ B

I'm confused on the commas and what their meaning is here. In my truth table, am I to OR them all together?

Comment: More like (informal) and.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are to prove that $B$ must be true whenever all of the three other conditions are simultaneously true.

Comment: Ahhh, that makes sense. Cheers!!

Comment: I actually made a mistake with one of the implies tables. The expression is correct! I've removed that comment.

Comment: Good deal! Nicely done.

Answer (score 0):

First of all — no, all the formulas to the left of $\models$ are to be "and"ed together. So, you are to establish what assignments of values to variables make the following formula true:
$$
[(A \rightarrow B)\land (C \rightarrow A \lor B)\land C]\to B.\tag{*}
$$
Note that $(A \rightarrow B)\land (C \rightarrow A \lor B)$ implies $(C \rightarrow B \lor B)$, or equivalently, $C\to B$. Now, given $C$, by Modus Ponens we can infer $B$.

So the formula (*) is simply valid, true under all interpretations, a tautology.